# How can I edit a google doc with vi and automatically update the original doc in the cloud when I write the file?

Tags: ubuntu, vim, google-docs, google-workspace, vi

I'm using ubuntu 11.04. I have installed [googlecl](http://code.google.com/p/googlecl/) which claims to allow me to edit google doc files with vim. I have a google doc "test":

```
google docs edit --title "test" --editor vim
```

opens the file fine. When I write the file via the vim command `:w` the change isn't propagated to the original google doc in the cloud. Also, when I `:wq`, I get this command line output:

```
Server responded with: 412, <errors xmlns='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005'><error><domain>GData</domain><code>etagsMismatch</code><internalReason>Mismatch: etags = ["tags"], version = [gqpwmaue]</internalReason></error></errors>
Moved edited document to /home/james/test.txt
```

How can I automatically update the original doc when I save it in vim?

Comment: I've never heard about googlecl so I installed it on Ubuntu 10.10 and I have almost the same problems. Maybe try on the googlecl [issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/googlecl/issues/list).

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if you solved the problem, but I was encountering the same error on my machine. This was happening because I didn't have the latest python-gdata package. GoogleCL package alone won't do the job.

Comment: I made sure to use the 2.0.14 version of gdata. Apparently later versions have issues. But note that I /did/ come across your error before with this version - but I figured that was a connection or document-type-dependent thing, because afterward it worked fine.